# Filtering out empty strings in Snowflake

Tags: sql, filtering, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, blank-line

I have a very simple task which is turning out to be impossible. I have a column that has strings but also has blanks where it supposed to be a word (those are not NULLs they are just empty strings). For example:

```
LastName1,
EmptyRow,
LastName2,
EmptyRow,
EmptyRow,
LastName3...
```

Since empty rows are not NULLs, IS NOT NULL function is not working.

In the end result, I just need to filter out all rows that actually have values in them and get rid of all the empty rows. Can someone please give a suggestion?

Answer (score 12):

You can filter out these records by applying LENGTH function to it.

```
WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(COL_NAME)) > 0
```

Comment: Careful with the sister version: `where length(trim(colname)) = 0`, it will also evaluate to false with a null value!

Answer (score 4):

If there is a mix of single spaces, no spaces and nulls, I uses something like this

```sql
WHERE COALESCE(TRIM( lastname ), '') <> ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what "empty" row means.  Most likely an empty string:

```
where lastname > ''
```

If you need to be sure that there is at least one letter you can use:

```
where lastname regexp '[a-zA-Z]'
```

or:

```
where lastname regexp '[[:alpha:]]'
```